# Specific Order on multiple items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of actions that are either Enable or Disable, with a value to indicate true or false. Functionally, an Enable:True is equivalent to a Disable:False (the wo types exists for other legacy reasons).

I have a need to resolve a list of actions into a single relevant action, where an action resulting in a disable takes priority. i.e. If one action indicates that it should disable the target, and all other say it should enable them, then the disable wins.

I've come up with the code below:

```
void Main()
{
    var actions = GetActions();

    var x = actions.OrderBy(A => (A.ActionType == ActionType.Enable && A.Value)
                                || (A.ActionType == ActionType.Disable && !A.Value)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Initial Order");
    x.Dump();

    x = x.Skip(1).ToList();

    actions.RemoveAll(A => x.Contains(A));

    Console.WriteLine("End Result");
    actions.Dump();
}

private List<Action> GetActions()
{
    var actions = new List<Action>();

    actions.Add(new Action() { ActionType = ActionType.Enable, Value = true });
    actions.Add(new Action() { ActionType = ActionType.Enable, Value = false });
    actions.Add(new Action() { ActionType = ActionType.Disable, Value = true });
    actions.Add(new Action() { ActionType = ActionType.Disable, Value = false });

    return actions;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Action
{
    public ActionType ActionType { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public enum ActionType
{
    Enable,
    Disable
}
```

This gives me exactly what I want (i.e. a single record that indicates a disable action should take place). It also works no matter what values are set for the ActionType enum values (or even the Enum text).

The problem is, I don't understand why, and I'm concerned that something might cause it to not work.

Based on the order:

```
var x = actions.OrderBy(A => (A.ActionType == ActionType.Enable && A.Value)
                            || (A.ActionType == ActionType.ADisable && !A.Value)).ToList();

    // Order Is:
    // Enable  False
    // Disable True
    // Enable  True
    // Disable False
```

I would have expected that it would sort Enable:True and Disable:False at the top of the list, but it's actually putting them to the bottom of the list. Thats what I *want*, but *why* is it doing that?

Comment: By default boolean sort order is FALSE then TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your ordering

```
Enable + false => false

Disable + false => false

Enable + true => true

Disable + false => true
```

As **false comes before true when ordering boolean values**, the result is correct.
Probably because `0 < 1` (well, at least that's the way it's implemented) ?

Just use `OrderByDescending` if you want true first (but that's not what you want).

But with your code, you won't be able to ensure the order between

```
Enable true
```

and

```
Disable false
```

for example.

Comment: Ah, ok. So its evaluating the condition I've specified and outputting as `true` or `false`, then ordering on the boolean output. That makes sense. In my case, Enable:true and Disable:false are equivalent, so that is fine for my purposes - I just wanted to fully understand the logic so that I could be sure it would continue to work as intended. Thanks

Comment: @Obsidian Phoenix To understand the logic, you need to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Your lambda expression actually selects the key, by which items should be sorted. It is readily apparent that expression returns a bool, what may not be is to what every possible case of Enabled/Disabled true/false evaluated to (and the fact that in bool sorting false is before true), and that part is covered in above answer.